# JQueryUI Drag & Drop - Nested Lists That Can't Switch 'Levels'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use JQuery UI to set up a system of nested, sortable lists but I don't want children becoming parents and vice versa. My basic code is right from the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HT8QB/1/

The borders make it a bit hard to see, but in the fiddle you can drag the children up to the parent level and then can't move them back. You also can't move the children from the first parent to the second.

Based on the documentation I think I can solve the second issue w/ the connect lists functionality, but I'm not sure how to solve the first ([preventing an item moving from one level to the other).

Comment: Your fiddle is broken. Can you fix it?

Comment: Ugh, sorry. Fixed! Still getting the hang of jsfiddle.

Comment: @Brad - not sure what you mean by works fine? I did change the link to a properly working fiddle, but when I test in Firefox, I can move the children up to the parent level, which is what I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, instead of trying to re-invent the wheel, I've decided to use the nestedSortable plugin: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/. It looks like it does everything we need out of the box, so no more random flailing.

Thanks anyways.